# Highlight `SquishedCommas`, except at end of line

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

Following up on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141649/how-do-i-highlight-commas-not-followed-by-a-space-in-vim) question on how to highlight commas not followed by a space; the accepted answer provides a nice solution for problems like:

```
func(a, b,c,d)
```

But it also highlights commas at the end of a line (after `longname2`):

```
func(longname1, longname2,
     longname3)
```

There I would actually like to highlight the opposite case, i.e. if there actually was a space behind `longname2,` (which is already handled by the highlighting of trailing spaces).

Is there a way to extend/modify this command:

```
highlight SquishedCommas ctermbg=red guibg=red
match SquishedCommas /, \@!/
```

To only highlight the `SquishedCommas` if they are not at the end of a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> match SquishedCommas /, \@!/

You are actively highlighting commas, that are not followed by a space. But in fact you want to only highlight commas that are not at the end of line and are not followed by a space. I think this change to your `:match` command will achieve this:

```
match SquishedCommas /,\%($\| \)\@!/
```

That will highlight commas, that are not at the end of the line and not followed by a space.

Note: the `:match` function is a window local function. That means it won't work after splitting a new window.

Comment: I always get crazy by things like `/,\%($\| \)\@!/` and have to study exactly how it works, but I just tested it and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!